which build-system shall be used with pyproject.toml to install system packages (Linux only, no windows)
I want to transition existing python 2.7 code base (2 .py files, nothing big) from 10+ years ago to python3 and more modern level of project handling. Python2 to python3 steps are out of scope here.
As part of it, I plan to introduce pyproject.toml file to specify build process instead of manual execution of steps from README file.
At this stage it's about build-system choice, where build system can read from TOML file a) list of names of system packages to install (e.g. like Debian packages) and b) (optionally) execute simple steps like fetching with CURL external archive, creating directory and unzipping archive there, and alike, i.e. nothing complex.
It's not going to be PyPI package, at least I do not see it necessary.
Most likely wheel artifact will be necessary.
I'd like to avoid poetry unless it's the only choice, and then to understand why it's the only choice.
I'm not planning any compatibility with Windows (not even WSL) or macOS, so these are NOT requirements in choice of build system.
I spent few hours in search, mainly within Stack Exchange and general search across web, to find which build system I shall even try, but no luck.
Again, this is small project of 2 python files and build against numpy and scikit, plus few binary libraries and gfortran, so no rocket science is expected.
It might be I ask wrong question and I shall e.g. look for build-frontend or any other steps to achieve what I want, feel free to comment.

What had been searched/tried

Google search for external advise about "pyproject.toml build system install system dependencies" and other variants of keywords, including forcing with "build system" syntax, exclusion with -windows and limiting search to site:stackexchange.com in multiple ways. And reading various links from search, like:

Migration from setup.py to pyproject.toml: how to specify package name?
How to write a minimally working pyproject.toml file that can install packages?
and many others


Reading documentation

Writing your pyproject.toml
Glossary: Build Backend
and few more from same site
documentation for pip, PDM, flite, etc




I think you are just looking for https://pypi.org/project/build/. It's not in the standard library, but it's in the same tier of tools as pip: basically standard, but 3rd-party so that its upgrade cycle isn't tied to Python's upgrade cycle. It is maintained by the Python Packaging Authority, just like pip.

Are you looking to do what PEP-725 is proposing? https://peps.python.org/pep-0725/

And a discussion at: https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-725-specifying-external-dependencies-in-pyproject-toml/31888

@ukBaz thank you, these are very valid and valuable hints for further search

What you are looking for does not exist in the PyPA-based ecosystem (i.e. pip, wheel, PyPI, etc.). In the future, maybe PEP725 will open the possibility, but today it's just not a thing. -- If I am not mistaken, you might get close enough in the conda ecosystem. In the conda ecosystem you can install things that are not Python, but they are still not installed as system dependencies.

You cannot get what you want with wheels. To install system dependencies you need to convert you package to system format: deb or rpm. See https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/ and https://pypi.org/search/?q=deb
